# Bootstrap 3.3.7 - Loading gif in button when running a function on another route

Tags: flask, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask-bootstrap

I have some buttons on my flask app, that when clicked trigger a function on a different route. I want to add a loading gif when the page is waiting for the function to complete. I have tried a dozen examples from SO but I've had no luck. Note,I am on bootstrap 3.3.7 so I can't use the

HTML:
 for route /dashboard (button lives here)

```
{% block styles %}
<!-- Bootstrap latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom-base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Pretty loading buttons -->
<link  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/loading-btn.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

<!-- run function-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Run Model</h2>
           <div class="container" align="left">
                <a href="/run_model" target="">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary ">Run</button></a>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% block scripts %}
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


{% endblock %}
```

Routes: 
the button links to the run_model function, executes and redirects
to the dashboard page.

```
{% block content %}

@app.route('/run_model')
def run_model():
try:
    # run a machine learning mode


except:
    # if errors found flash some error
    flash('Looks like something went wrong. Please try again! :(', 'danger')

return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
{% endblock %}
```

So essentially, I am looking to animate the button while still on the /dashboard page when the browser is "Waiting for `127.0.0.1:5000/run_model`
to complete and be redirected back to `/dashboard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a javascript issue, and not really a flask issue. After you click on a link, and get redirected, all javascript/css is killed. So after clicking on a button, first display your loading icon, and then redirect to whatever page you want:

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader" style="display:none;"></div>

<div  id="myDiv" style="display:block" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
  <a href="/run_model" target=""><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="testfunc()">Run</button></a>
</div>

<script>


function testfunc(){
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none"
  setTimeout(redirect, 5)

}

function redirect(){
  window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Modified from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Comment: thanks this worked well. Too bad I can't have a loading button. In anycase, how can I add a dim screen when the loading css is activated? Can't say I have much experience with javascript!